# Java and Google API : Connect to google mail and add event in my google calendar?

Tags: java, google-api, google-calendar-api

I program in Java in applicative with JavaFX, I send my "object" if we can call it that way, in my excel, but I would have liked friends, to send it on my google calendar. To connect, I would have liked to put my address in hard and my password in hard because there is only me who will use the program.
Only, I have read and reread the google api documentation (and I understand half of it apparently I have to connect to Oauth and then send the data to the calendar, I have the access keys by the way) but I understand almost nothing I have never used an API.

In summary: I would like to connect to my google email address and send an event to my google calendar:

- choiceBoxCategorie + " " + choiceBoxEquipeA + " " + choiceBoxEquipeB for the event title.
- datePickerDateMatch for the date event.
- ChoiceBoxHeure + ":" + ChoiceBoxMin for the event hours
- choiceBoxAdresse for the event address
- textFieldNotes in the event notes

the event go in my calendar "Calendar AWBB"

In my excel a exemple result is :

- Date : 26-06-21
- hours : 05:45
- Championship : Championship
- Category : U21HB
- State : Program
- Equipe A : BC Gen
- Equipe B :  BC Ran
- Adress : Hall Omnisports - Europe Avenue, 6000 Georgetown
- Notes : The match is good

Thanks all :)

Here is my function that needs this code:

```
@FXML
protected void EnvoiDonneesChampionnat()
{
    /*Call service*/
    SvcResultat Create = new SvcResultat();
    /*data correct ?*/
    if(datePickerDateMatch.getValue()==null || choiceBoxAdresse.getValue()==null || choiceBoxMin.getValue()==null || choiceBoxCategorie.getValue()==null ||
    choiceBoxEquipeA.getValue()==null || choiceBoxEquipeB.getValue()==null || choiceBoxHeure.getValue()==null){
        erreur.setText("Data is missing");
    }
    else {
        /*Create objet*/
        String result = datePickerDateMatch.getValue().toString()+";"+choiceBoxHeure.getValue().toString()+":"
                +choiceBoxMin.getValue().toString()+";Championnat;"+choiceBoxCategorie.getValue().toString()+";Programm\\u00e9;"
                +choiceBoxEquipeA.getValue().toString()+";;;"+choiceBoxEquipeB.getValue().toString()+";"
                +choiceBoxCategorie.getValue().toString()+";"+choiceBoxAdresse.getValue().toString()+";"
                +textFieldCollegue.getText()+";"+textFieldNotes.getText();
        System.out.println(result);
        /*Object go in my excel*/
        Create.ajoutResultat(result);

    }
 // method for create a google calendar event
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the [Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api) documentation there are guides on how to use the API with java.

You can use two of the guides / examples. The first one is the [Quickstart guide on Java](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/java) that will show you how to execute the API.

The other one is the [Create Events](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/create-events#java) guide where you have an example on creating an event with Java.

Combine both and you will create an event to your account through the API

This is the code for both:

Quickstart:

```java
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.DateTime;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.CalendarScopes;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Event;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Events;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class CalendarQuickstart {
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Google Calendar API Java Quickstart";
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    private static final String TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH = "tokens";

    /**
     * Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
     * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved tokens/ folder.
     */
    private static final List<String> SCOPES = Collections.singletonList(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR_READONLY);
    private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "/credentials.json";

    /**
     * Creates an authorized Credential object.
     * @param HTTP_TRANSPORT The network HTTP Transport.
     * @return An authorized Credential object.
     * @throws IOException If the credentials.json file cannot be found.
     */
    private static Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT) throws IOException {
        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in = CalendarQuickstart.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        if (in == null) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        }
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .build();
        LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
        return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        // Build a new authorized API client service.
        final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        Calendar service = new Calendar.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();

        // List the next 10 events from the primary calendar.
        DateTime now = new DateTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
        Events events = service.events().list("primary")
                .setMaxResults(10)
                .setTimeMin(now)
                .setOrderBy("startTime")
                .setSingleEvents(true)
                .execute();
        List<Event> items = events.getItems();
        if (items.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("No upcoming events found.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Upcoming events");
            for (Event event : items) {
                DateTime start = event.getStart().getDateTime();
                if (start == null) {
                    start = event.getStart().getDate();
                }
                System.out.printf("%s (%s)\n", event.getSummary(), start);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Create events:

```java
// Refer to the Java quickstart on how to setup the environment:
// https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/java
// Change the scope to CalendarScopes.CALENDAR and delete any stored
// credentials.

Event event = new Event()
    .setSummary("Google I/O 2015")
    .setLocation("800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103")
    .setDescription("A chance to hear more about Google's developer products.");

DateTime startDateTime = new DateTime("2015-05-28T09:00:00-07:00");
EventDateTime start = new EventDateTime()
    .setDateTime(startDateTime)
    .setTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");
event.setStart(start);

DateTime endDateTime = new DateTime("2015-05-28T17:00:00-07:00");
EventDateTime end = new EventDateTime()
    .setDateTime(endDateTime)
    .setTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");
event.setEnd(end);

String[] recurrence = new String[] {"RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2"};
event.setRecurrence(Arrays.asList(recurrence));

EventAttendee[] attendees = new EventAttendee[] {
    new EventAttendee().setEmail("lpage@example.com"),
    new EventAttendee().setEmail("sbrin@example.com"),
};
event.setAttendees(Arrays.asList(attendees));

EventReminder[] reminderOverrides = new EventReminder[] {
    new EventReminder().setMethod("email").setMinutes(24 * 60),
    new EventReminder().setMethod("popup").setMinutes(10),
};
Event.Reminders reminders = new Event.Reminders()
    .setUseDefault(false)
    .setOverrides(Arrays.asList(reminderOverrides));
event.setReminders(reminders);

String calendarId = "primary";
event = service.events().insert(calendarId, event).execute();
System.out.printf("Event created: %s\n", event.getHtmlLink());
```